# PostgreSQL and pivot tables using crosstab function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a problem with creating a pivot table in PostgreSQL using the `crosstab()` function. It works well but it produces multiple records for the same `client_id`. How can I avoid this?

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab('SELECT client_id
                     ,extract(year from date)
                     ,sum(amount)
               from   orders
               group  by extract(year from date)
                     ,client_id'
             ,'SELECT extract(year from date)
               FROM   orders
               GROUP  BY extract(year from date)
               order  by extract(year from date)')
AS orders(
row_name integer,
year_2001 text,
year_2002 text,
year_2003 text,
year_2004 text,
year_2005 text,
year_2006 text,
year_2007 text,
year_2008 text,
year_2009 text,
year_2010 text,
year_2011 text);
```

//Edit

Thx to Erwin it works now, but I have tried to do this without built in function with no luck. Can someone suggest something on that? My code for only two years:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.client_id,
       CASE WHEN (extract(year from o.date)=2001)
            THEN sum(o.amount) ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN (extract(year from o.date)=2002)
            THEN sum(o.amount) ELSE 0 END
FROM orders AS o
GROUP BY 1, extract(year from o.date)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `ORDER BY` the first query accordingly. I use the [simplified syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) `ORDER BY <ordinal number>` here.

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
        'SELECT client_id
               ,extract(year from date)
               ,sum(amount)
         FROM   orders
         GROUP  BY 1,2
         ORDER  BY 1,2',

        'SELECT extract(year from date)
         FROM   orders
         GROUP  BY 1
         ORDER  BY 1')
AS orders(
    row_name integer,
    year_2001 text,
    year_2002 text,
    year_2003 text,
    year_2004 text,
    year_2005 text,
    year_2006 text,
    year_2007 text,
    year_2008 text,
    year_2009 text,
    year_2010 text,
    year_2011 text);
```

The `crosstab()` function is not included in standard PostgreSQL but comes with the [additional module tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html).

#### Edit for additional request

Version without `crosstab()` function:
Only group by `client_id` or you will end up with multiple rows per `client_id`.

```
SELECT client_id
      ,sum(CASE WHEN extract(year from date) = 2001 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS year_2001
      ,sum(CASE WHEN extract(year from date) = 2002 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS year_2002
       -- ...
FROM   orders o
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it is working now. After solving this I have tried to do this without built in function but no luck, can you look at my edit and try to help me?

Comment: @GabrielFilipiak: I amended my answer with a non-crosstab version.

Comment: Thanks, so I was so close with that :)

Comment: @GabrielFilipiak: Yep, pretty close. :)