# Get timestamps from a table with the count of rows per interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate

I need an SQL query to aggregate a time series from a Postgres table. I would like the time series to show the amount of rows created in a given time frame (i.e. weekly or daily).

The table data looks like this:

| id | dateCreated(timestamp) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-15 14:47:39 |
| 2 | 2020-10-15 14:47:39 |
| 3 | 2020-10-15 14:47:39 |
| 4 | 2020-10-16 14:47:39 |
| 5 | 2020-10-16 14:47:39 |
| 6 | 2020-10-17 14:47:39 |
| 7 | 2020-10-17 14:47:39 |
| 8 | 2020-10-17 14:47:39 |
| 9 | 2020-10-17 14:47:39 |

And the time series I would like as an out put would be some thing like this:

| date(timestamp) | numberOfRowCreated |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10-15 14:47:39 | 3 |
| 2020-10-16 14:47:39 | 2 |
| 2020-10-16 14:47:39 | 4 |

Answer (score 2):

Basic [aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```sql
SELECT dateCreated, count(*) AS nr_of_rows
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY dateCreated
ORDER  BY dateCreated;
```

To group by day / week / month / ... , use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', dateCreated) AS day, count(*) AS nr_of_rows
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Related:

- [date_trunc 5 minute interval in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165827/date-trunc-5-minute-interval-in-postgresql/12167385#12167385)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

About the [short syntax with ordinal number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

- [PostgreSQL and pivot tables using crosstab function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027293/postgresql-and-pivot-tables-using-crosstab-function/8029193#8029193)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thank you!! That works but the days still have to be the exact same value, I would like it to work by grouping either by day or by week.

Comment: @Cooper: Added a bit.